# Translate a string date in a numeric date

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I have a date expressed by string, i.e. January 28, 2021 and I would like to express it in a mm/dd/yyyy date, so from "*January 28, 2021*" to "*28/01/2021*".

My approach was to tokenize the string in these tokens: "28", "January", "2021", using LEFT, MID and RIGHT formulae.

Now I would have to use the DATE command: whereas day and year are recognized without issue as they are already expressed in number, I can't translate "January" to "1", even googling for the solution, as no solution seems to work using Excel for Office 365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your months are not in "English", so you need to translate the months into a month number, and use that in the date function.

Since you have O365, you can use this:

```
=LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),y,DATE(INDEX(x,3),MATCH(INDEX(x,1),{"January";"February";"March";"April";"May";"June";"July";"August";"September";"October";"November";"December"},0),INDEX(x,2)),y)
```

`FILTERXML` breaks the date string into the three componenents.
`MATCH` is used to translate the month into a month number.

Once you get the result (for today it would be a five digit number `44224`), you can then format it how you wish using the cell format dialog.

Comment: You're right. It worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a genuine date and then format it.

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2),",","") & "-" & LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1) & "-" & RIGHT(A1,4))
```

and then formatting will work:

[image]

This works because `28-January-2021` is a string that `DATEVALUE()` will accept.
**EDIT#1**
In fact, depending on your Locale, this might also work:

```
=DATEVALUE(A1)
```

Comment: Comma-separated arguments in function seem not working for me, I think I have to change seperator from semicolumn to comma as explained in this article? https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/commas-stop-working-in-formulas/

Comment: @EagleOne  **Yes** ................also see my edit.

Comment: =DATEVALUE is not working with my locale (solution 2), and even after changing list separator in Windows settings, It just seems not working. Even replacing commas with semicolumns didn't do the trick

Comment: @EagleOne  Have you tried to select the cell containing the source data and re-format it ???

Comment: I have changed the formula in =SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1;FIND(" ";A1)+1;2);";";"") & "-" & LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1)-1) & "-" & RIGHT(A1;4) that returns "28-January-2021" while DATEVALUE("28-January-2021") produces a #VALUE! error

Comment: Translating the month in current document language works

Comment: @EagleOne  Are you satisfied with your solution??

Answer (score 0):

You can just click at the cell where the date is in and than format it as a „Time/Date-Cell“. Excel should automatically detect that as a date and format it right.

Comment: Used CTRL+1, selected Date and the date format I'm looking for, but it didn't change the cell content